# md-datepicker wrong input- AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-material

When the non-existent date is selected in the input manually- the date in the calendar shows what I expect, but input- does not. I have the following:

```
<md-datepicker name="startDate" class="custom-datepicker" ng-model="models.startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-required="true"
               md-max-date="models.maxDate" ng-change="onDateChange()">
</md-datepicker>
```

So, when i manually input Feb 31 i see:
[image]

and when calendar is opened: [image]

I have already found the solution (changing the value in the "onDateChange" function), but this calendar is used smth like 30 times and i want to avoid adding those everywhere. Are there any other solutions that may help (probably filter or smth else you can advise)?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation I am getting this code:

`<md-datepicker ng-model="birthday"></md-datepicker>`

Your implementation is:

`<md-datepicker name="startDate" class="custom-datepicker" ng-model="models.startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-required="true"
               md-max-date="models.maxDate" ng-change="onDateChange()">
</md-datepicker>`

Since you have already done the 2-Way Data Binding using `ng-model` on `models.startDate` there is no need to alter the value of the model using `onDateChange()` function.
Please further specify the contents of your JS file to address ambiguity.